# Expecting authentication method via either a service token

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openstack

Sorry for my beginner's level question.

I have OpenStack installed. When I try to execute this command

```
keystone user-list
```

I get this

```
  Expecting authentication method via
  either a service token, --os-token or env[OS_SERVICE_TOKEN], 
  or credentials, --os-username or env[OS_USERNAME].
```

How do I specify a token?

Comment: it is the same error when creating admin user with Service Token.

Answer (score -1):

You need to source the permissions file, depending on the way you installed OpenStack this is different.

If you did devstack install, its "`cd devstack` followed by `source openrc`
If you did packstack install its `. /root/keystonerc_admin`